# How to print a variable on a html table with php

Tags: php

Hi guys i have the following code and i can't understand why it give an error

```
syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)
```

I have a variable:`$Email=$_SESSION['Email'];`

And i wont print it on my html table :

```
<tr>
    <th>Email</th>
    <td><?= echo $Email ?></td>
</tr>
```

I have alredy tryed everything, but it still don't work...I think that i am trying to print a variable with the wrong command, but i don't know any other way...

Comment: Remove `echo`.
`<td><?= $Email ?></td>`

is enough

Comment: Wow thank you it work!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for shorthand expressions is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)

What you want is either:

```
<?= $Email ?>
```

or, not shorthand,

```
<?php echo $Email; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

```
<?=$Email;?>
```